# IntelliJ IDEA Edu - Compile Java with Gradle to slow on Win 10

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, windows-10, compiler-optimization

I use IntelliJ IDEA Edu on my PC (Win 10 Edu, AMD 5 3600X 3.80 GHz, 16 GB RAM, 5700XT 8 GB GDDR) and on my Notebook Huawai Matebook X Pro (Win 10 Home, Intel I7 8550 1.8 GHz, 16 GB Ram, Nvidia MX150)

My Notebook needs 3 - 4 sec to run a Java Test Class, my PC needs for the same Test more than 3.5 minutes. I checked many threads and blogs and imported my IntelliJ settings from my Notebook on to my pc. But I cannot improve the performance.

[image: Snapshot from PC]

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antivirus/firewall or any similar security tool can affect build and run performance a lot, please refer to these support documents describing how you can fix it:

- [Antivirus Impact on Build Speed](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560-Antivirus-Impact-on-Build-Speed)
- [Slow startup on Windows: splash screen appears in more than 20 seconds](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005028939-Slow-startup-on-Windows-splash-screen-appears-in-more-than-20-seconds)

To further diagnose such issues you can use `jstack` to [get the thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544899) of the processes (IDE process, Gradle process and the JVM that actually runs your tests) to see what's happening.

In most cases the execution would be paused for a long time until the real-time antivirus monitor completes the process scan which in some cases can take several minutes.

Comment: Thank You, I tried these but don't really help. I made these jstack dump logs. And send them to Jet Brains.

I hope somebody have another solution

Comment: Where did you send the files? Can't find them in the support tickets or at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I submited a request with the button on the top of the site

Comment: i repost it now on youtrack with the same text

Comment: YouTrack report for the reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246141.